# assignment inside subclass declaration - React.Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, syntax, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-next

I'm going through Egghead's React tutorial and in one of the lessons I found the following class declaration:

```
class StopWatch extends React.Component {
        state = {lapse: 0, running: false}

        render() {
            const {lapse, running} = this.state
            const buttonStyles = {
                border: '1px solid #ccc',
                background: '#fff',
                fontSize: '2em',
                padding: 15,
                margin: 5,
                width: 200
            }
            return (
                <div style={{textAlign: 'center'}}>
                    <label style={{fontSize: '5em', display: 'block'}}>
                        {lapse}ms
                    </label>
                    <button style={buttonStyles}>{running ? 'Stop' : 'Start'}</button>
                    <button style={buttonStyles}>Clear</button>
                </div>
            )

        }
    }
```

So looking at the code, I was just curious about that assignment on the top. I looked at the class and extends documentations on MDN and it doesn't say anything about allowing an assignment inside a class declaration.

Furthermore, I tried it on a sample code and it's throwing an error:

```
class Square {
        constructor(prop1, prop2) {
            this.prop1 = prop1
            this.prop2 = prop2
        }
    }

    class Polygon extends Square {
        constructor(prop1, prop2, prop3) {
            super(prop1, prop2)
        }
        prop2 = prop3
        render() {
            console.log(prop2)
        }
    }
```

So... why does it work?

Comment: check this [diff between state = {} and constructor(){....}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45451141/what-is-the-difference-between-using-constructor-vs-state-to-declare-state)

Comment: The problem is: in your test `prop2` is the property of class so try accessing `this.prop2` from `render`. Also, what is `prop3`outside the constructor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The subclass uses class fields which are [stage 3 proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields) and aren't a part of existing standard. They provide syntactic sugar for constructor body. As explained in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49600432/3731501), there's a specific order in which class field assignments are performed.

The subclass is identical to this ES6 class (check also [Babel output](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&code_lz=FAAhGMBsEMGdZABQPaQJ4HNkDsQFMAPAFz2wBMEBlARwFdoAnPEAb1DA_B1iIdvCLIGACgAODZKICMAGhDjJAJjkLRAZgCUrdh10hYtUXhGrZ8iaMUadHAL42wqxSAC85yWocgm5Y8K1senpc2LCoeAB0kMgYYhZWXvZg9kA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&fileSize=false&lineWrap=true&presets=es2017%2Cstage-0&prettier=false&targets=Node-6.9&version=6.26.0&envVersion=1.6.2) to get some ideas what's going on):

```
class Polygon extends Square {
    constructor(prop1, prop2, prop3_that_doesnt_collide) {
        super(prop1, prop2);
        this.prop2 = prop3;
    }

    render() {
        console.log(prop2)
    }
}
```

`console.log(prop2)` refers to non-existing `prop2` variable and not `prop2` property.

Notice that because `prop3` was located outside constructor method, it doesn't refer to `prop3` constructor parameter but to some non-existing `prop3` variable, so `prop3_that_doesnt_collide` parameter and `prop3` don't collide.

Since `prop2` assignment relies on constructor parameter, it should be placed inside constructor method:

```
class Polygon extends Square {
    constructor(prop1, prop2, prop3) {
        super(prop1, prop2);
        this.prop2 = prop3;
    }

    render() {
        console.log(this.prop2)
    }
}
```

Since it just immediately replaces `prop2` value with `prop3`, it can be:

```
constructor(prop1, prop2, prop3) {
    super(prop1, prop3);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax you're trying to use is not standardized and you'll need Babel to transpile your code. Alternatively you can use static members in classes -

```
let Foo = class {
  static get staticData() {
    return 'Static Data';
  }
}

console.log(Foo.staticData);
```

Comment: Surprisingly, you'll need Babel to develop React because of JSX :)